# Google maps places request returning undefined results?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to place a place request using google maps' places API but My results are always undefined?

Any suggestions? My other functions are able to correctly initialize the map object and I can see my map with markers without this place function?

If anyone could spot an error in this function I'd be extremely grateful!

```
    $scope.placeRequest = function(map){
                var location = new google.maps.LatLng(39.6303225,-106.57294);
                var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

                service.nearbySearch({
                    location: location,
                    radius: 5000,
                    types: ['lodging','art_gallery','restaurant','bar', 'spa','museum']
                }, callback());

                function callback(results, status) {
                console.log(results);
                    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                            $scope.places.push(results[i]);
                        }
                    }
                };
            };
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  Note two things: 1. the `types` option is deprecated and will no longer be supported. 2. Your function is not indicating the status when it fails, that might provide additional information on why you aren't getting results.

Comment: use simply `callback`, not `callback()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results are always undefined because you are using the `callback` parameter incorrectly.  This syntax is not correct, it calls the `callback` function and uses the results of that call (null) as the callback function:

```
service.nearbySearch({
    location: location,
    radius: 5000,
    types: ['lodging','art_gallery','restaurant','bar', 'spa','museum']
            }, callback());
```

It should be:

```
service.nearbySearch({
    location: location,
    radius: 5000,
    types: ['lodging','art_gallery','restaurant','bar', 'spa','museum']
            }, callback);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/pt1xq1ff/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var infowindow;
var $scope = {
  places: []
};

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(39.6303225, -106.57294);
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  service.nearbySearch({
    location: map.getCenter(),
    radius: 5000,
    types: ['lodging', 'art_gallery', 'restaurant', 'bar', 'spa', 'museum']
  }, callback);

  function callback(results, status) {
    console.log(results);
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        console.log(results[i].name + ":" + results[i].geometry.location);
        $scope.places.push(results[i]);
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    } else alert("places request failed, status=" + status)
  };

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location,
      title: place.name
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```